# Align field in HorizontalFieldManager

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

I created a custom `HorizontalFieldManager` where I can position the fields using   `setPositionChild()` and `layoutChild()`. It works fine if I add `LabelField` to it. The problem is when I add labels to a `VerticalFieldManager` and add that VFM to my custom HFM. The issue is it does not take the preferred height of the VFM. Any idea why?

```
 setPositionChild(
      getField(0), 
      0, 
      0);
 layoutChild(
      getField(0), 
      getField(0).getPreferredWidth(), 
      getField(0).getPreferredHeight()); //.....
      setExtent(width, height);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
 Manager customManager = new Manager(0)
 {
 protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
     setPositionChild(
         getField(0), 
         0, 
         0);
     layoutChild(
         getField(0), 
         getField(0).getPreferredWidth(), 
         getField(0).getPreferredHeight());

     setPositionChild(
         getField(1), 
         Graphics.getScreenWidth()/2 - getField(1).getPreferredWidth()/2, 
         0);
     layoutChild(
         getField(1), 
         getField(1).getPreferredWidth(), 
         getField(1).getPreferredHeight());    

     setPositionChild(
         getField(2), 
         Graphics.getScreenWidth() - getField(2).getPreferredWidth(), 
         0);
     layoutChild(
         getField(2), 
         getField(2).getPreferredWidth(), 
         getField(2).getPreferredHeight());    

     setExtent(width, height);
 }
```

};
 customManager.add(new LabelField("Hello Alignment"));

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding more than one fields then give layout for all fields.

And if using only one field then no need to give layouts, let it add to manager.